# It's said that `libX11` is not thread-safe. Does this mean I can't mix Java AWT with something else that also uses X11, like Qt?

Tags: java, multithreading, qt, awt, x11

It's said that `libX11` is not thread-safe. Does this mean that if I have a Java application that already uses AWT (either directly, or indirectly through Swing), that I can't use another toolkit (like Qt, or some other library that uses X11) besides it (in the same process)?

To my understanding, the toolkits wouldn't know of each other, would start their own event handling threads on top of `libX11` and therefore use `libX11` in multiple threads, which sounds problematic because `libX11` is not thread-safe.

Or does AWT have some means that I'm not aware of to synchronize with other users of `libX11` within the same process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have separate toplevel windows, it should be easy to mix the toolkits. You can also mix them in the same window, but it is tricky (you need to merge the event loops) and ugly.

> Qt Jambi implements its own event system based on Qt/C++. This event loop is separate from the one in other toolkits such as AWT/Swing or in SWT. As a concequence, it is not possible to have Jambi widgets and widgets from other toolkits in the same part of the user interface. Having a toplevel window running Jambi and another toplevel window running AWT/Swing does not run into this limitation.
>
> Although it is possible to merge event loops for different toolkits, so that a QPushButton can inhabit a JSplitPane, it often not desired as this means that different parts of the same user inteface may have slightly different look&feel. Different repaint behaviour, fonts etc.

[source](http://qtjambi.org/doc/design)

Comment: *"it should be easy"* Only if the windows don't share state.

Comment: @Radiodef Easy in the sense that the two toolkits receive different events because events are associated to top-level windows on the Xlib level.

Comment: Does that mean that when I have two toplevel windows that I have two xclients?

Comment: No, a client is an entire process, but as far as I understand it, it does not matter: each toolkit will be interested in the events associated with the windows created by themselves. Note that I am not an expert in these issues, but I assume that the Qt Jambi authors are. Also see this: http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_08.html